# How to access the array of json objects in angular component

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have the below data from api call:

how to bind this data to component.html page in angular.
even with NgFor loop also fine

```json
[
    {
        "newsCategory": "Corporate",
        "newsHead": "header data",
        "newsDate": "20-01-2020",
        "newsContent": "something comkdnf"
    },
  {
        "newsCategory": "hjhds",
        "newsHead": "hjkhbksd",
        "newsDate": "20-01-2020",
        "newsContent": "jhvjchddnf"
    },
]
```

My code:

```html
///// Some elements are there in html.
<div>{{news[0].newsDate}}</div>
<div>{{news[0].newsCategory}}</div>
<div>{{news[0].newsHead}}</div>
```

```typescript
constructor(public _newsService : NewsService) { }
newsdetails:allNewsArray[]

ngOnInit(): void {
this._newsService.getNews().subscribe(
       (news : allNewsArray[])=>{console.log(typeof(newsdetails[0]))}
);}


export class allNewsArray {​​​​​​​​
newsCategory: string;
newsHead: string;
newsDate: string;
newsContent: string;
}​​​​​​​​
```

in console log value is coming.. but not able to bind it in the component html

Answer (score 4):

You are currently not binding your data from your `.subscribe()` to your variable in your class. The following will fix your issues:

```
HTML

<div *ngFor="let news of newsdetails">
  <div>{{ news.newsDate }}</div>
  <div>{{ news.newsCategory }}</div>
  <div>{{ news.newsHead }}</div>
</div>
```

```
COMPONENT

newsdetails: allNewsArray[];

ngOnInit(): void {
  this._newsService.getNews().subscribe(
    (news: allNewsArray[]) => this.newsdetails = news
  );
}
```